# auto_increment gap on fail insert

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

At the moment, we are using Python and MySQL. Within the Python script, we use the `mysql.connector` library to write the data over to the database. We have constraints on a few tables so that redundant data is not written to the database, however, if a failed insert occurs, the auto_increment value creates a gap between the row_id. So the primary key in the table is row_id, set with auto_increment constraint.

We have attempted to play with the `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode` with no luck. We are running MySQL80 instance locally on Windows 7.

Is there a better way to approach the gap when the insert statement fails? Ideally, we would like no gaps.

Comment: I have to ask why this is important. The primary key should not have any intrinisic value by itself. The primary key's only job is to uniquely identify a row in the table (which it does).

Comment: @Vince0789 Our system is inserting data multiple times a day, and within two pulls we are already at 10,000 in ID's because some statements fail due to redundant data.